# In Basketball, if the ball goes through the hoop and net twice in one shot, how many points?

Tags: rules, basketball

I've just seen a video where a player shoots the basketball during a game.

The ball initially enters the hoop and passes completely through the net. However the net flicks the ball in a way that sends the ball back over the top of the hoop from the outside of the home's cylinder (over the top of the hoop). The ball then passes back through the hoop and net for the second time after the initial shot.

Is this counted as two successful shots? How many points is it worth if the player shoots from outside the 3 point line?

Comment: I'm having a hard time believing that isn't a doctored video. The net shouldn't have enough mass to alter the trajectory of a basketball to that extent.

Answer (score 3):

Two points (or three if it were a three-pointer etc).

Quoting from [Article 10 "Status of the ball" from the FIBA 2020 rulebook](http://www.fiba.basketball/documents/official-basketball-rules/2020.pdf):

> 10.3 The ball becomes dead when: Any field goal or free throw is made.